# merging a list of data frames having multiple columns, only unique column name is date_time, some columns names are same, some are different

Tags: r, dataframe

```
dat1 <- data.frame(Date_Time = c("20120628", "20120629 1045", "20120723 1100", "20120726 1500"),
                          O = c(2345, 4567, 6780, 3456),
                         '2000C' = c(NA, 250, 100, NA),
                          PUT.1 = c(4, NA, 50, 50),
                         '3000C' = c(NA, 45, 50, 70),
                          PUT.2 = c(50, 40, NA, 20))

dat2 <- data.frame(Date_Time = c("20120728 1200", "20120829 1145", "20120923 1100", "201201026 1400"),
                   O = c(4345, 4567, 5080, 4456),
                   '4000C' = c(NA, 250, 100, NA),
                   PUT.4 = c(4, NA, 50, 50),
                   '5000C' = c(NA, 45, 50, 70),
                   PUT.5 = c(50, 40, NA, 20))
```

These are reproducible examples, i have a list of data frames as above, i wants to merge them all, however there are multiple column names in each, which are keeps changing in all the data frames.Pls help

I have already used 
`res <- merge(dt1, dt2, by = ("Date_Time"), all.x = TRUE)`, though only to see whether only two `dt` gets merged on not, but it only shows the `Date_Time` column values for one of the `dt`, and not for the other, i do not not see the `date_time` column for the other df being merged. Pls help been stck with this problem from quite some time.

Comment: 1) Have a little bit understanding of what `Join` of two tables means will help you, which is equivalent to `merge` in R; 2) Figuring out what you want the output to be will help, it will be even better if you can show the desired output to us so that we can help;

Answer (score 0):

```
dt1 <- data.table(Date_Time = c("20120628", "20120629 1045", "20120723 1100", "20120726 1500"),
                  O = c(2345, 4567, 6780, 3456),
                  '2000C' = c(NA, 250, 100, NA),
                  PUT.1 = c(4, NA, 50, 50),
                  '3000C' = c(NA, 45, 50, 70),
                  PUT.2 = c(50, 40, NA, 20))

dt2 <- data.table(Date_Time = c("20120728 1200", "20120829 1145", "20120923 1100", "201201026 1400"),
                  O = c(4345, 4567, 5080, 4456),
                  '4000C' = c(NA, 250, 100, NA),
                  PUT.4 = c(4, NA, 50, 50),
                  '5000C' = c(NA, 45, 50, 70),
                  PUT.5 = c(50, 40, NA, 20))

res <- merge(dt1, dt2, by = ("Date_Time"), all.x = TRUE)
```